# Mask a canvas with image

Tags: html, canvas, mask

This is the situation: I need to do a "splatter" effect to show the content behind (be it a body background image, or a google map). I'm thinking of overlaying a canvas on top of the actual content. The canvas will have an opaque (white) background initially. Then, I'll mask it with the splatter images and `interval` to show the underlying content.

I've found this fiddle that does something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/VqCbv/43/
However, the mask is drawn with `fillRec` and `createLinearGradient` Can I modify the code somehow to use an actual image for the mask, for a more flexible shape?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to first create and load in an image with the "splatter". Then you set composition mode of the canvas to `destination-out` and simply draw the image on top of your canvas:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

What will happen is that all pixels that are in the image will remove the pixels on the canvas leaving the area the image was in as a transparent area. The other pixels (the white) will be intact.

Demonstration (click canvas to splatter):
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/4A4Qv/

As you can see a hole is punched in the canvas so the background is visible.